# Get Class in which current test case is running in Junit

Tags: java, junit4

Is there any way to get class of current test case executing. By @Rule annotation we can get method name of current test method but to get class I am not able to find the way by which I can get class.

```
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
  Method method=MyClass.class.getMethod(testName.getMethodName());
```

}

I want to get Myclass so that I can achieve generalization in above code for any class containing test method.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get class name use

```
@Test
public void setUp() throws Exception
    Class clazz = this.getClass(); //if you want to get Class object
    String name = clazz.getSimpleName(); //you want to get only class simple name
}
```